# Как вывести список из MySql, отсортированный по выбранной категории в RecyclerView

Tags: android, mysql, recyclerview

Здравствуйте! Есть две таблицы в базе данных MySql: в одной названия отделов, в другой названия отделов и имена людей. В android вывожу первую таблицу в RecyclerView. Нажимаем на название отдела и открывается новая activity с новой RecyclerView, в которой нужно вывести вторую таблицу, но только имена людей, которые соответствуют выбранному отделу.Во втором активити принял имя отдела с первого активити его для последующего использования (как я понимаю, он нужен будет). Вопрос в том как его использовать для отправки на сервер, чтобы отработал php скрипт ($name=$_POST['otdel']; $sql="SELECT name FROM listnames WHERE otdel = '$name'";)

1. Из первого активити открываю второй и передаю строку имя выбранного отдела

   ```
   openDetailActivity(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
   private void openDetailActivity(String otdel)
   {
       Intent i=new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
       i.putExtra("Otdel",otdel);
       context.startActivity(i);
   }
   ```
2. Открывается второй активити, принимается строка переданная из первого активити и выводится весь список имен (а хочется только имена выбранного отдела)

   ```
   public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       List<GetDataAdapter> GetDataAdapter1;
       RecyclerView recyclerView;
       RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;
       RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;
       String tab2= "http://10.204.1.97/Android/names/tab2.php";
       String name_url = "name";
       JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;
       RequestQueue requestQueue ;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
           Intent i=this.getIntent();
           String otdel=i.getExtras().getString("Otdel");
           GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();
           recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
           recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
           recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
           recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);
           JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();
       }

       public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){
           jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(tab2,
               new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                       JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                   }
               },
               new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   }
               });

           requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
           requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
       }

       public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){
           for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
               GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();
               JSONObject json = null;
               try {
                   json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                   GetDataAdapter2.setImageName(json.getString(name_url));
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
           }
           recyclerViewadapter = new Connector(GetDataAdapter1, this);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
       }
   }
   ```
3. класс GetDataAdapter

   ```
   public class GetDataAdapter {
       public String ImageName;
       public String getImageName() {
           return ImageName;
       }

   public void setImageName(String imageName) {
       this.ImageName = imageName;
   }
   ```
4. класс Connector

   ```
   public class Connector extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Connector.ViewHolder> {
       Context context;
       List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;
       public Connector(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){
           super();
           this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.names_detail, parent, false);
           ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
           return viewHolder;
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {
           final GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);
           Viewholder.ImageName.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageName());
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return getDataAdapter.size();
       }

      class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
           public TextView ImageName;
           public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
               super(itemView);
               ImageName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: добавь код.....

Comment: @alex_andr89 добавьте код, как сделали запрос, чтобы заполнялся ваш 1й recyclerview

Comment: @pavlofff добавил информацию ниже

Comment: @zayn1991 добавил информацию ниже

Comment: На этом сайте впервые. Простите за корявую вставку текста

Comment: @alex_andr89 вам надо не в ответах написать, а в вопросе добавить реализацию) исправьте)

Comment: Добавил код  в вопрос

Comment: Исправил в коде имя передаваемого аргумента. Во втором активити принял его для последующего использования (как я понимаю, он нужен будет). Вопрос в том как его использовать для отправки на сервер, чтобы отработал php скрипт ($name=$_POST['otdel'];
$sql="SELECT name FROM listnames WHERE otdel = '$name'";)

Comment: Если ваша проблема в том, как отправить из клиента  на сервер данные для запроса, то именно это и надо писать в вопросе (а не  в комментарии через 5 дней)